# jqplot neighbor issue

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am a brand new with jqplot, so please excuse my ignorance. I have inherited an app that generates an OHLC chart. Each series is shown with a vertical line ranging from the min to the max, with a tick mark at the average. There are jqplotClick and jqplotMouseMove functions defined that both start with:

```
   if (neighbor) {
```

My problem is that when the series contains only one data point - i.e. O == H == L == C (in that case it's rendered with just the tick mark and no line), neighbor is null and the click and mouse move actions don't happen. I've been asked to modify it so that these actions do occur on these single point series.

Since there is a data point, why is neighbor null? How can I make this work in those cases?

TIA!

Here is more info in response to dnagirl's post.

This is the series passed into jqplot:

```
[
Array[4]
0: Array[6]
0: 1
1: 59.351
2: 62.621
3: 55.89
4: 59.351
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[6]
0: 2
1: 60.805
2: 60.805
3: 60.805
4: 60.805
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[6]
0: 3
1: 59.7385
2: 62.224
3: 57.947
4: 59.7385
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
3: Array[6]
0: 4
1: 58.9365
2: 59.48
3: 58.393
4: 58.9365
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[4]
0: Array[3]
0: 1
1: 1
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[3]
0: 2
1: 3
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[3]
0: 3
1: null
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
3: Array[3]
0: 4
1: 2
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

And here is picture of the chart:

[image: And here is picture of the chart]

I've traced this into the checkIntersection function in jqplot. The issue is that if you have a OHLC chart and O==H==L==C the neighbor is not picked up. In this block the if is never true:

```
else if (!r.hlc){
    var yp = s._yaxis.series_u2p;
    if (x >= p[0]-r._tickLength && x <= p[0]+r._tickLength && y >= yp(s.data[j][2]) && y <= yp(s.data[j][3])) {
        return {seriesIndex: i, pointIndex:j, gridData:p, data:s.data[j]};
    }
}
```

But when O, H, and L are not equal, it does return true.

Comment: if you could post a pic of the current output, and some of the data, it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I updated my post with the info you requested.

Comment: Can you post your code or even better a jsfiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: The code is huge, and I'm trying to put together a minimal example, but it's not easy. I tried to put something on jsfiddle, but jqplot doesn't seem to work there. I've traced the code into the checkIntersection function in jqplot. The issue is that if you have an OHLC chart and if there's a point where O==H==L==C, then the neighbor is not picked up. I'll update my original post with more info.

Comment: So I think the issue is that when it wants to see if the y point is between the low and the high:

`     y >= yp(s.data[j][2]) && y <= yp(s.data[j][3])`

and the low and high are equal, you have to be on the point with so much accuracy that it's virtually impossible. I think the code needs to test for low == high and apply some tolerance.